# i++ In python showing me error

Tags: python

I cant use `i++` in python. My code is

```
i=0
while i<10:
   print i
   i++
```

But it works fine if I replace `i++` with `i=i+1` it works. What have I done wrong

Comment: python won't support this feature. You could use `i +=1`

Comment: "What have I done wrong": You have used `++` in a python program.

Comment: so I should be hanged????

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: or at least sent off to read the language documentation.

Answer (score 4):

There is no ++ operator in python. You must use

```
i += 1
```

Comment: i+=i+1 is not equal to i++

Comment: I have noticed, right after:) But thanks for reminding:)

Comment: Even `i += 1` is not the same what you expected `i++` to do. Integers are immutable in Python. With `i += 1` you create a new integer behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4):

It's just that `i++` isn't supported in python. Replace that loop as follows:

```
i=0
while i<10:
   print i
   i += 1 # add 1 to i.
```

Or, even better (in case you are indeed using loops that way):

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    print i
```

Please take a look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm) for a list of all operators.